# React router v6 using javaScript objects and material-ui tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

recently I've started working on a react app and I have a task in which I need to create some tabs. When clicking on any tab I have to load the page that the selected tab should display. I also have to change the url depending upon selected tab (my area is not around client side techologies so I simply am stuck)

The layout should be something like this

[image]

and what I have to do is this, on selecting Menu2 Item, I have to display the tabs, on selecting a tab I should load its content.

the url format should be something like this (localhost:80/menu2-item/tab1/{item1} , where {item1} can be an item selected from the content.

In the app I have something like this which I see that it is used by useRoutes hook.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    element: <DashboardLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <AccountView /> },
      { path: 'account', element: <AccountView /> },
      { path: 'control-center', element: <ControlCenterLayout /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  }
];


const App = () => {
  const routing = useRoutes(routes);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      {routing}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

The DashboardLayout, has an Outlet element in it, from what I've read this is used to display child routes, which I guess are the "children" specified in the routes object. What I have to do is the ControlCenterLayout part.

I've updated the ControlCenterLayout part in the routes object and how it looks something like this

```
 {
    path: 'control-center',
    element: <ControlCenterLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'item1', element: <Item1View/> },
      { path: 'item2', element: <Item2View/> },
    ]
  },
```

Created a TopBar element

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Paper, Tabs, Tab} from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

const TopBar = ({ className, ...rest }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newTab) => {
    setTab(newTab);
  };

  return (
    <Paper square className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs value={tab} onChange={handleChange} >
        <Tab label="Item1View"  />
        <Tab label="Item2View" />
      </Tabs>    
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

An index.js which references the TopBar

```
const ControlCenterLayout = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <TopBar />
        <div className={classes.wrapper}>
          <div className={classes.contentContainer}>
            <div className={classes.content}>
              <Outlet />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

But I have no idea on how to use routing and material-ui Tabs to obtain the result, nor if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Can you put that in a sandbox? So we can see how it works together.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add AppBar inside BrowserRouter

```
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs
            variant="fullWidth"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            aria-label="nav tabs example"
          >
            <LinkTab label="Main" pathname="/" {...a11yProps(0)} />
            <LinkTab label="Users" pathname="/users" {...a11yProps(0)} />
            <LinkTab label="Me" pathname="/users/me" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
          <Route path="users" element={<Users />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<UsersIndex />} />
            <Route path="me" element={<OwnUserProfile />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<Other />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Also, provision Material UI Tab component to behave like Link component
Link with `component={Link}` prop.

[image]

Check attached working Sandbox Url.
https://codesandbox.io/s/muitabs-v6routing-5odvz?file=/src/index.js

fixed left drawer navigation as well. I hope this helps